How to manipulate JSF viewstate in during the web scrap using C# ASP.NET Core
Currently, I'm changing some selenium automations for web scraping on a website that uses java faces .jsf, when trying to make a request with C# and httpclient
the server responds with an xml error:

faces.application.ViewExpiredException

This is an example of the body HTTP call I'm using:
            var postData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ice.window", "pnm15d2rfi"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ice.view", "v98u1snc8nx:0"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("form:num_contrato_input", $"{varnumber}"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("form_SUBMIT", "1"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("javax.faces.ClientWindow", "pnm15d2rfi"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("javax.faces.ViewState", $"{Viewstate}"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("com.sun.faces.namingContainerId", ""),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ice.focus", "form:checkAuthBtn_Consultar"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("form:checkAuthBtn_Consultar", "Consultar"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ice.event.target", "form:checkAuthBtn_Consultar"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ice.event.captured", "form:checkAuthBtn_Consultar"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ice.event.type", "onclick"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ice.event.alt", "false"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ice.event.ctrl", "false"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ice.event.shift", "false"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ice.event.meta", "false"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ice.event.x", "840"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ice.event.y", "274"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ice.event.left", "true"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ice.event.right", "false"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ice.submit.type", "ice.s"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ice.submit.serialization", "form"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("javax.faces.partial.event", "click"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("javax.faces.source", "form:checkAuthBtn_Consultar"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("javax.faces.partial.ajax", "true"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("javax.faces.partial.execute", "@all"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("javax.faces.partial.render", "@all"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("form", "form")
            });

            var responsePost = await client.PostAsync(URLWEBSITE, postData);
            var resultContent = await responsePost.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(resultContent);

Am I missing something? It is necessary to decrypt the viewstate?
I tried use one hardcoded value in view state
